# Can I set java 11 by gradle in android project?

Tags: java, android, gradle, java-11

I need to set java 11 for build android project anywhere (on build machine for example). I found [gradle feature toolchain](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html) but I can't find right way to use it in android project. I tried to add in app module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 

//first way
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
    }
}

android {
    //second way
    java {
        toolchain {
            languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
        }
    }
```

but I still get error:

> Task :my-library-module-name:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED  An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_282). Please file a bug
> against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page
> (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database
> (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the
> following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
> java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute
> name MODULE (class
> com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)

where my-library-module-name this is my another android lib gradle module which connected to app module.

It is possible to use gradle toolchain in android project?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem.
Both the ways you mentioned produce the same result.

**Adding the compileOptions in android** block worked for me.
If you haven't already, try adding it with the same java version as in the toolchain.

```
android {
    someBlock{...}
    java {
        toolchain {
            languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}
```